# XMonad spawn programs on startup in specified workspace

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I am trying to configure my `xmonad.hs` so that when I start my session I start an array of different programs on different workspaces (like Terminal in 1 ; Firefox in 2 ; Pidgin in 3).

I already looked into the `XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn`, but as `spawnOn` returns with an `X ()` and not with a common `m ()` I can not use it in `main = do ...`.

Is there a function that takes an `X`-monad and returns with `IO ()` or is there another workaround?

Comment: X is an instance of Monad, so `X ()` works with `m ()` - you can use do-notation with `X ()` actions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The common way is to use [startupHook](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad/0.10/doc/html/XMonad-Core.html#v:startupHook) which takes `X ()` action and performs it on each startup.
E.g.

```
main = xmonad $ defaultConfig
  { startupHook = do
      spawnOn "workspace1" "program1"
      …
      spawnOn "workspaceN" "programN"
  }
```

Comment: I called my workspaces according to their function "Terminal" "Web" "Chat" etc. , but passing these names as arguments for the spawnOn function does not work with certain programs (such as eclipse). I am currently working around it with setting up Manage Hooks for each application, like className =? "Firefox" --> doF(W.shift (customWorkspaces !! 1)) and spawning them with a regular spawn

Comment: Note `spawnOn` is from the xmonad-contrib package

Comment: I've got    { startupHook = do
          spawnOn "workspace2" "emacs"
        },  but the program is just started on the first workspace after login, or the current workspace if I restart xmonad.

Comment: 1) what are the default workspace names? 2) this will start new apps on a reload, not just a fresh startup. How can this guard against a restart?