# xmonad auto start apps on login, but not reloads

Tags: xmonad

I am trying to set up auto start of my main applications.

Following [xmonad spawn on startup in different workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976044/) I have added the following to my `startupHook`

```
startup :: X ()
startup = do
          setWMName "LG3D"
          spawnOn "workspace1" "urxvt"
          spawnOn "workspace2" "emacs"
          spawnOn "workspace3" "chromium"
```

but there are three problems:

1. I am duplicating the definition of my terminal. It seems like I should be using [`shellPromptOn`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-SpawnOn.html) but it takes an extra parameter and I don't know where to get it from.
2. this is putting everything on my current workspace. How can I find out what my workspaces are called? I don't believe I've customised the names, you can see [my .xmonad/xmonad.hs on github to confirm](https://github.com/fommil/dotfiles/blob/master/.xmonad/xmonad.hs)
3. this will start the apps again on a `xmonad --restart`. How can we guard against that? It is very useful to be able to restart xmonad without quitting and I don't want to lose that ability.

Comment: Were you able to solve the second point? I am using the same procedure and mine are also starting on the current workspace. Similar to you, I did not change my workspace names either.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can move your terminal value into a function that can both be called by xmonad and startup.

`terminal = "urxvt"`

`spawnOn "workspace1" terminal`

3. Not a complete solution but just thought I'd mention there is
   [spawnOnce](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Util-SpawnOnce.html#v:spawnOnce) - it doesn't allow you to select a spawning workspace though.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2. case, I was able to do something like following:

On my startup, I have something similar to what the question shows but with changed workspace names

```
startup :: X ()
startup = do
          spawnOn "ed" "code-insiders"
          spawnOn "www" "opera" 
          spawnOn "slack" "slack"
```

Which makes them start on current workspace. To move them to respective workspaces, I had to add a `ManageHook` as follows:

```
myManageHook :: ManageHook
myManageHook = composeAll
   [ className =? "Code - Insiders" --> doShift "ed"
   , className =? "Opera"      --> doShift "www"
   , className =? "Slack"  --> doShift "slack"
   , manageDocks
   ]
```

To learn the `className` of an app, like "Code - Insiders" above, you need to run following in a terminal

```
$ xprop | grep WM_CLASS
```

and click on the window of desired program with the given mouse pointer. This will write the `className` onto terminal.