# How to start up xmonad with apps on other workspaces

Tags: haskell, x11, window-managers, xmonad

I'm trying to write an xmonad.hs which, at startup, launches some apps on some workspaces.  Several of these apps (e.g., `atop`) will run within a terminal (`urxvt` being my preference).

This has been asked a few times before, e.g, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976044/xmonad-spawn-programs-on-startup-in-specified-workspace), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/478498/start-applications-on-specific-workspaces-in-xmonad), and is obliquely touched on on the [XMonad FAQ](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/General_xmonad.hs_config_tips#Making_window_float_by_default.2C_or_send_it_to_specific_workspace).

However, these rely on:

1. using `spawnOn` from [`XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.15/docs/XMonad-Actions-SpawnOn.html), which flat doesn't work (testing with `urxvt`, and also `xclock` as a simple example); it gets sent to the current workspace.
2. using `spawn prog >> windows $ greedyView <workspace>`, which kinda works, but has major timing issues - e.g., if you run two in succession, with different workspaces, both progs end up on the latter workspace.  FWIW, I experimented with using threaddelay to assist; it didn't make any discernable difference, even with a 10s delay between spawns (I remembered that threadDelay is in microseconds, and so used 10000000).
3. rely on using general hooks for programs - meaning that *whenever* I start them up, they'll get sent to the given workspace.  That's not what I want; I just want them placed there at startup.

Relatedly, it surprises me that the API doesn't let me start up an app and then give me a reference to that app/window (potentially with a timeout); so that I can confidently send **that app/window** to a workspace.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems `spawnOn` is exactly what you need. I would just investigate why that isn't working. Possibly ask another question and provide a MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

Install wmctrl

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

And create a script (in this example thunderbird on the second workspace (`-t 1`)):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

 (thunderbird &)  & sleep 5 && 
sh -c "wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l | grep Thunderbird` -t 1"
```

To know your application name on wmctrl you can view it by taping on your terminal :

```
wmctrl -l
```

And replace it with the correct name in the script.

Be carrefull with the capital letter ("Thunderbird" not "thunderbird") !!

Other example with firefox on the 3d workspace (`-t 2`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
(firefox &)  & sleep 5 && 
sh -c "wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l | grep Firefox` -t 2"
```

## Bonus :

Here is the command to execute at start-up :

```sh
sh -c "thunderbird  & sleep 5 && wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l | grep Thunderbird` -t 1"
```

Work on Debain 10 with Cinnamon. But should work for all

Answer (score 1):

You can spawn the app via startupHook and then use a manageHook to handle window placement.

manageHook such as:

```
, className =? "deluge" --> doShift ( myWorkspaces !! 3 )
```

The above will actually spawn deluge on Workspace 4. In my startupHook I have

spawnOnce "deluge-gtk" to launch the app on start-up.

You would want to import XMonad.Util.SpawnOnce. doShift comes from the default XMonad.ManageHooks You could also take a look at XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn but I only use manageSpawn from that module.